# Задача по массиву

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Продолжаю изучать С#. Есть задача:

> На вход метода подаётся массив целых чисел. Метод должен вычислить
>   сумму всех чётных элементов.

Если ее решать не разбивая на методы, проблем нет, плевое дело. Но я решил сделать по правильному и разбить на методы. И сразу же появилась проблемы.
Я решил добавить два метода:
Первый метод будет находить в массиве четные числа
Второй метод будет эти четные числа складывать
Ну и main будет выводиться результат.
Вот мой код:

```
static int EvenNumber(int[] array)
    {
        //тут получение четных чисел из массива
        int evenNum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                evenNum = array[i];
            }
        }
        return evenNum; //это неправильно((
    }

    static int SummValue(int[] summ)
    {
        //получение суммы массива
        return summ.Sum();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arrays = { 2, 4, 3, 10, 1 };                      
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Как из метода EvenNumber вернуть четные числа массива и использовать их в методе SummValue? Чтоб потом вывести результат в main. 
Уже какой день бьюсь...
Спасибо заранее Всем за помощь!

Comment: `вернуть четные числа`, а вы возвращаете одно число (int). Сделайте на выход массив этих чисел (`static int[] EvenNumber...`), ну и формируйте массив с результатами, который на строке `evenNum = array[i];` заполняете, а через `return` возвращаете.

Comment: `static IEnumerable<int> EvenFilter(IEnumerable<int> source) => source.Where((item, index)=>index%2==0);`

Comment: `static int Sum(IEnumerable<int> source)=>source.Sum();`

Comment: За компилируемость не отвечаю, пишу с телефона, но идея должна быть ясна

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ будет как начинающему (с соотв. кодом) и с некоторыми рекомендациями.

Вот вы создали проект и написали первую строчку

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] inputArray = new[] { 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 7, 8, 6, 4, 0 };
}
```

что делать дальше? Размышлять письменно, т.е. писать комментарии вот так

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] inputArray = new[] { 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 7, 8, 6, 4, 0 };

    //получить массив четных чисел из входного массива

    //получить сумму четных чисел из массива

    //вывести результат на экран

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Поразмышляли? Начинаем писать код.

[image: первый этап]

Написали строки с несуществующими еще методами. Как быть? Пускай их за нас напишет студия. Вот так подводите мышку к подчеркнутым красным названию метода и вылезает такая подсказка, нажимаем `Enter` и нужный метод создан.
[image: функция студии]

Повторяем эту же операцию со вторым методом. И получаем второй метод. И программа почти готова!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] inputArray = new[] { 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 7, 8, 6, 4, 0 };

        //получить массив четных чисел из входного массива
        int[] evenNumbers = GetEvenNumbersArray(inputArray);
        //получить сумму четных чисел из массива
        int sum = GetSum(evenNumbers);
        //вывести результат на экран
        Console.WriteLine(sum);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int GetSum(int[] evenNumbers)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static int[] GetEvenNumbersArray(int[] inputArray)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Она даже компилируется! Но не выполняется...

Теперь размышляем над первым методом.

```
private static int[] GetEvenNumbersArray(int[] inputArray)
    {
        //создать массив-аккумулятор для сбора четн.чисел

        //пройти по аккумулятору и назначить всем элементам -1

        //выбрать в цикле четные и занести их в аккумулятор

        //подсчитать кол-во чисел не равных -1 в аккумуляторе

        //cоздать результирующий массив

        //внести в результирующий массив все числа не равные -1 из аккумулятора

        //вернуть результат

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Пишем код...

```
private static int[] GetEvenNumbersArray(int[] inputArray)
    {
        //создать массив-аккумулятор для сбора четн.чисел
        int[] accum = new int[inputArray.Length];
        //пройти по аккумулятору и назначить всем элементам -1
        for (int i = 0; i < accum.Length; i++)
        {
            accum[i] = -1;
        }
        //выбрать в цикле четные и занести их в аккумулятор
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inputArray[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                accum[i] = inputArray[i];
            }
        }
        //подсчитать кол-во чисел не равных -1 в аккумуляторе
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < accum.Length; i++)
        {
            if (accum[i] != -1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        //cоздать результирующий массив
        int[] result = new int[count];
        //внести в результирующий массив все числа не равные -1 из аккумулятора
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < accum.Length; i++)
        {
            if (accum[i] != -1)
            {
                result[j] = accum[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        //вернуть результат
        return result;
    }
```

Теперь можно проверить работу первого метода. Вернитесь в метод `Main()` и на вызове второго метода поставьте курсор и нажмите клавишу `F9`, или мышкой кликните слева на серой рамке напротив нужной строки.
[image: установка точки останова]
Таким образом мы установили точку останова. В режиме отладки программа остановится на этой строке и сможем проверить результат выполнения метода, вот так
[image: отображение результата выполнения метода]
наводите курсор мыши на нужную переменную и всплывает подсказка, в которой можно проверить результат выполнения метода.

В таком же духе продолжаем со вторым методом

```
private static int GetSum(int[] evenNumbers)
{
    //создать результирующую переменную
    int result = 0;
    //пройти в цикле по evenNumbers и просуммировать в результат
    for (int i = 0; i < evenNumbers.Length; i++)
    {
        result += evenNumbers[i];
    }
    //вернуть результат
    return result;
}
```

Все. Можно проверить работу программы. Точку останова можно отключить, если по ней кликнуть еще раз или повторно поставить курсор на эту строчку и нажать `F9`.

Вы скажите, что лень писать комментарии, а хочется сразу код. Когда вы только учитесь лучше сначала набросать канву решения в комментариях, а потом писать код. Такой режим работы помогает сохранить нить размышлений, и такой подход помогает даже опытным программистам в сложных и запутанных ситуациях.

Желаю успехов!

Comment: что-то подробностей маловато (

Comment: @Igor да, хотел еще подробнее, но не осилил:)

Comment: А вот вопрос: стоит ли добавить еще один метод, типа DataBase, чтоб в нем хранить данные полученный с методов: четные числа и сумма четных чисел. А в main уже вывод на экран сделать. Или бред?))

Comment: ты сделал промежуточное значение `evenNumbers` массивом. разве это не лишнее усложнение? почему бы не сделать через `IEnumerable<int>`? магия `Linq` с удовольствием все выполнит и ресурсов лишних не потратится - вычисления за один проход

Comment: @dgzargo я специально начал ответ так: "Ответ будет как начинающему (с соотв. кодом)...".